# Maven 2 - package org.junit does not exist

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

In my Maven 2 build JUnit is not found even though the dependency in the POM is present.

> `[ERROR] /project/web-test/src/java/com/domain/dialog/AbstractWebTest.java:[15,17] package org.junit does not exist`

What can be the problem? `mvn compile -X` has not yet provided the crucial information.

Comment: Can we see the relevant Maven dependency config ?

Comment: Is this a single pom or multi-pom project?  Can you please post the relevent portions of your pom?

Comment: Also do run the maven command with `-e` switch for detailed output.

Comment: Maybe you have a `<scope>test</scope>` in the dependency and the class `AbstractWebTest` does not reside under `src/test/java/`?

Answer (score 2):

The simple problem is that your class `AbstractWebTest` is not correctly located under `src/test/java`, cause usually all kind of test related parts have to be located in `src/test/java` instead of `src/main/java`. Furthermore you have to check if your dependency is correctly scoped to `test`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the simple problem.  

In this context, I also have a class from another project src / test / directory included.  

Maven reusing test classes across multi modules projects
http://www.waltercedric.com/java-j2ee-mainmenu-53/361-maven-build-system/1349-maven-reusing-test-classes-across-multi-modules-projects.html